# Error sound whenever Return key is pressed and doesn't even reach the event handler

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I'm writing a C# Windows Form program. The text boxes are for numbers and I don't want to process the number before it is completely entered. I've written the event handlers for processing after the return key is entered. What happens however is when I press the Return key I receive a Windows error sound. I initially thought I needed to handle this in the event handler but I discovered that when the Return key is pressed the keystroke never reaches the event handler. I've looked around for a property for the entire form to allow Return and ESC but cannot find any. Note: Tab key functions correctly.

This is the full source code so far:

```
namespace Magnetic_Loop_Antenna
{
    public partial class MagnetLoopAntenna : Form
    {
            // Constants
        public const double pi = 3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399;
        public static readonly double rad = pi / 180, DEG = 180 / pi;   // PI to RAD
        public const double solM = 299792458;       // Speed of light in meters/sec
        public const double solMm = solM / 1000;    // Speed of light in mega meters/sec
        public const double solFt = 983571056.43;  // Speed of light in feet/sec
        public const double ft2mtr = 0.3048;          // Convert factor for Feet to Meters


            // Default Parameters
        public static int units = imperial;                  // Units to work in, Imperial or Metric
        public static double D = 60;                        // Loop diameter
        public static double C = D * pi;                   // Loop Circumfrence
        public static double conductorD = 0.375;      // Conductor diameter
        public static double RL = 0;                        // Added loss resistance 
        public static double xmitP = 25;                  // RF xmitter power
        public static double freq = 14.1;                 // Frequence

        public MagnetLoopAntenna()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Start off filling the form with some default parameter values

            tbDsgnFreq.Text = "14.1";           // Antenna Design Frequence
            tbLoopDia.Text = "60";                // Primary Loop Diameter
            tbConductDia.Text = "0.375";       // Diameter of the conductor 
                                                          //  used to make the loop
            tbAddedLoss.Text = "0";             // Any aditional losses not accounted for
            tbMaxPower.Text = "25";             // Maximum RF Power to be applied
                                                          // This is important to determine
                                                          //   the minimum variable capacitor
                                                          //   plate spacing to prevent arcing
        }

        private void tbDsgnFreq_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double junk;
            junk = 1.0; // Used to put a breakpoint within the event handler
        }
        private void tbDsgnFreq_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
            {
                freq = Convert.ToDouble(tbDsgnFreq.Text);
            }
        }

        private void tbLoopDia_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void tbConductDia_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void tbAddedLoss_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void tbMaxPower_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Anyone have any thoughts?

Bruce

Comment: Please note: the title is incorrect.  After starting this thread I found that the initial thoughts were incorrect but forgot to change the title.  I'm new here so please be patient while I get use to the way things work.  BTW: if anyone knows how to edit or delete a post please let me kmow

Comment: Thoughts: The enter key is not handled by the TextBox when you don't set `AcceptsReturn`. But the form handles the return key by checking its `AcceptButton` property and performing the click handler of that button (if you have set an acceptbutton). The esc key is never handled by a normal textbox. You can derive your own overriding `IsInputKey()` method to do this. I guess it's easier to change the UX approach on _what_ should happen _when_.

Comment: You can use the [edit] link below the question and edit the title, maybe to "Handling ESC and Return in TextBoxes" or something

Comment: The error sound appears because you didn't set an `AcceptButton` for the form. But from your goal description that wouldn't solve your issues.

Comment: btw: there is a `Math.PI`, you don't need to declare it yourself.

Comment: Hmmm, I've found the AcceptButton property, it says (none) and I can't find a way to change it.  There is only (none) in the dropdown list

Comment: Don't set `AcceptsButton` on your Form if you don't need it, it raises the target's button click event and the event stops propagating, it would only make your problem worse. I tried to do a repro here with only a text box with a KeyDown event handler and it works. What else do you have in your form? Could you try to isolate this code in a new project to see if it works for you?

Comment: I did not mean to suggest to set the `AcceptButton`, I just wanted to explain what happens when you hit the return key.

Comment: I will give that a try and let you know if it works

Comment: Well I set up a test project, 1 form, 1 textbox 1 KeyDown event handler (I'm assuming the KeyDown handler is outside of the TextBox event handler) but it behaved the same way.

Comment: Continued...  I then put a test variable in the KeyDown handler and set a breakpoint there and the Return key never reached it.  I also put a test variable and breakpoint in the textbox handler and it never reached that either; I saw in the "Programing with Windows Forms.pdf" where he/she suggested adding this line of code after the InitializeComponent method : this.AcceptButton = btnOK; btnOK is not a valid constant so I'm at a loss what is meant by btnOK unless its it's suppose to all another method.

Comment: However I don't see how that would work unless it sets a form property because we don't reenter the form once the CR is pressed

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, when you type the Escape key on a form, the only thing it does is to operate the button set in the form's `CancelButton` property; you may be able to get around your issue using a button where the `Visible` property is set to `false`.

As to the Return key, the `Textbox` has a property called `AcceptsReturn`; this is set by default to `false`, but you can set it to `true` in the designer.

Comment: Solved. I hope this helps others trying to fight the same issue.  Solution is quiet simple.  Just put this in your KeyDown event: e.SuppressKeyPress = True;